# What is a “prisme de lecture”?

Tags: expressions

I recently heard the expression “prisme de lecture”. I did not find any definition on Internet.

What is a “prisme de lecture”?

Comment: A personal bias when analysing situations

Comment: Where did you see it? There is some internet post that says if you put a prism in front of your eyes, you can see everything. I doubt that. Prisms angle light.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Employé au figuré, « prisme » signifie « voir de façon déformée » voir la définition dans le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/prisme) :

> B. − Au fig. Élément transformant l'image du réel, généralement en la déformant. Le prisme de l'amour. Le prisme de l'amour-propre (Ac.).Pour un homme seul, les choses perdent la moitié de leur intérêt. La famille a un prisme qui rend l'aspect de toutes choses plus satisfaisant (Duranty, Malh. H.Gérard, 1860, p.146).
>
> ♦ Voir qqc. à travers un prisme. Voir la réalité de façon déformée, transformée. Le prisme des préjugés. Me rapporterait-il ma douce imprévoyance Et le prisme charmant de l'inexpérience? (Desb.-Valm., Élégies, 1833, p.110).J'ai vu Tahiti trop délicieuse et trop étrange, à travers le prisme enchanteur de mon extrême jeunesse (Loti, Mariage, 1882, p.294).

Answer (score 2):

French here.

It's like the mindset, your paradigme, the way you see the world.
Everybody has a different "prisme", then everybody see his own reality.

"you have to change your reading prism" it's like "you need to upgrade/change your mindset"